MAUI - How to change color or decoration of a Span
I've created a hyperlink using FormattedString. How can I add effects like on hover add an underline, or change color of a visited link? I've following code so far:
var formattedString = new FormattedString();
var link = "http://www.google.com/";
var hyperlinkSpan = new Span { Text = "Click me"};
hyperlinkSpan.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
{
    Command = new Command(async () =>
    {
        await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri(link)).ConfigureAwait(true);
    })
});
formattedString.Spans.Add(hyperlinkSpan);

I am able to add underline to the Span using TextDecorations="Underline", but in this case link is always underlined. I want it to be underlined only on hover.

A .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) pointer gesture recognizer detects when the pointer enters, exits, and moves within a view. But when you add a pointer recognizer to a Span, it will throw the error, "PointerGestureRecognizer is not supported on a Span".
Right now, PointerGestureRecognizer works on Label. Maybe you could add the gesture on Label and trigger the Property change when hovering the label (not the span).
        mylabel.GestureRecognizers.Add(new PointerGestureRecognizer
        {
            PointerEnteredCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                hyperlinkSpan.TextColor = Colors.Blue;
                hyperlinkSpan.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
            }),
            PointerExitedCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                hyperlinkSpan.TextColor = Colors.Black;
                hyperlinkSpan.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.None;
            })
        });  

Or just use Label instead of Span with StackLayout or Grid to manage the UI.
By the way, you could consider raising a feature request on GitHub for this.
